# Стеганография. bmp -> jpg, png и т.д

Tags: расширения, jpeg, bmp, стеганография

Как происходит процесс изменения картинку в формате bmp в jpg и обратно? Если зашифровать в bmp текст так, что его можно прочитать, а потом преобразовать в jpg, а потом обратно в bmp, получится опять прочитать текст внутри bmp?

Comment: Если вы имеете ввиду какие-то мета данные в файле, которые не видны в изображении, то нет. Погуглите EXIF метки, мб поможет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет, не получится. Jpg - формат с потерями. Даже bmp без стеганографии будет отличаться от оригинала, если его сохранить в жипег и назад в бмп.

Как происходит процесс преобразования в двух словах не объяснишь, читайте спецлитературу.

Comment: Понял, спасибо!